# TinyMCE display correct image path from frontend

Tags: php, tinymce-4

How i can display the correct url for the image uploaded using TinyMCE?
I get a file not found error, this because when I load the created contents on the frontend, the `src` attribute of the images contained inside the post are referring to my img path like this `../../img/prt/image.jpg`, and it's the correct path for the backend, but from the index i need that the src is set to `img/prt/image.jpg` that is the correct path. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution for this. After reading the related section of the documentations, I've solved using the `convert_urls` option of the editor.
This is the third time I use this kind of editor, so I didn't know about all available options.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/#convert_urls

example code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
    convert_urls: false
  });

});
```